# Water density as a function of temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, physical-chemistry, density

I would like to know if there is an expression or a correlation to calculate water (not gas or steam) at different temperatures. If possible both nonlinear and linear temperature calculation. I only know of the Boussinesq approximation $$\rho = \rho_0 ( 1+\beta(T-T_0))$$
where $\rho_0$ is the reference density at $T_0$ (reference temperature) and $\beta$ is the thermal expansion coefficient.

I prefer not to use this model because my 1D code that I am trying to develop do not work with this model. Also, for some reason I saw online a lot of people suggesting to use the ideal gas low but this is not gas but rather  pure water liquid.

Comment: The water anomaly site has links: http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/density_anomalies.html#density

Comment: Is this at a fixed pressure (if so what pressure)?  Also, Note that your Boussinesq approximation likely is _really bad_ for this purpose.  It assumes the thermal expansion coefficient is constant; which doesn't hold for water over a wide enough range of temperatures (for example, around 4°C, water is most dense, then gets less dense again as it goes lower and as it goes higher, so that approximation wouldn't hold since the expansion coefficient has to change; increasing temperature goes from increasing the density, to decreasing the density, a constant $\beta$ doesn't reflect that).

Comment: The pressure is constant for now at 1bar and the starting  temperature of the system is 300 K. Yeah I do realise that the approximation will not work with my system that is why I am trying to find another expression that will hopefully work. I will later have a higher pressure up to 10 bar and at the final stage I will add a change in pressure to reflect real problems. But for now has a constant pressure of 1 bar.